# How to attach a scrollbar to the right of a datagrid inside a div?

Tags: asp.net, datagrid, scrollbar

I am creating a scrollable `div` containing a Datagrid like so:-

```
<div id="myDiv"
     style="overflow: auto; height: 300px; "
     onscroll="myFunction();">
     <asp:DataGrid id="gradesGrid"
     .
     .
     .
     </asp:DataGrid>
</div>
```

and the scrollbar duly appears. But instead of being attached to the right of the contents of the `div`, as I was hoping, it is obscuring the right-hand edge of the DataGrid. This causes an annoying horizontal scroll bar to appear. Is there any way to persuade the `div` to attach the scrollbar to the outside of the DataGrid rather than over the top of it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know this **currently is not supported.**

If you don't mind about the slight cut off from the vertical scroll bar in your div simply apply the following:

```
overflow-x: hidden;
```

To hide the horizontal scroll bar (above), or increase the size of your div = the pixel width of a scroll bar. Maybe implement some padding?

```
padding-right: <value of the width of the scrollbar>;
```

**Edit:** *The reason I am suggesting padding is because you said you wanted it on the outside, which for now you cannot do, but if it was on the outside other content would then have to be adjusted with a margin or padding - so really it doesn't matter (that is probably a reason why you cannot set the scroll bar outside in the first place).

E.g. if you had the scroll bar outside, and it was 10px wide you would REQUIRE a rule on some other div, or whatever was next to it, to have a margin of 10px on the side of it that "touches" that scroll bar. It's easier to just add padding on the containing element.* **End of edit.**

You can also set the width of the scroll bar, example on webkit:

```
::-webkit-scrollbar 
{
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
}
```

Here is a very exaggerated example: http://jsfiddle.net/eFhnN/

Comment: Thank you. The `padding-right` option is what I chose, and it's working splendidly.